# How can I add form elements in custom form on click of link?

Tags: forms, ajax

I want to add form elements inside my custom form when some body clicks on the link outside the form. Links are like :

- Add textfield
- Add selectlist

When user click on any link it via ajax add an element to the form. I just want and idea whether it is possible or not in drupal. If it is possible then just give me some idea about this.

Thanks

Comment: You should take a look at [Examples module](https://drupal.org/project/examples) or in particular the AJAX example https://api.drupal.org/api/examples/ajax_example!ajax_example.module/7 It's really helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is absolutely possible.  I would highly recommend that you check out Drupals [AJAX framework](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!ajax.inc/group/ajax/7) and [Form API](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7).

You might even be able to use the Form API's ["#states' features](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#states) to accomplish what you're looking to do without having to make any AJAX callbacks.

There is also the [Examples for Developers](https://drupal.org/project/examples) project that I believe contains code that accomplishes what your hoping to accomplish.

These should help you get started with the AJAX framework in Drupal.